# Gradient to solid color coreplot

Tags: ios, core-plot

So right now I am graphing the colors of my bar with a

```
self.helloPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:79.0f/255.0f green:178.0f/255.0f blue:204.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] horizontalBars:YES];
self.helloPlot.identifier = TickerSymbolHELLO;
```

My goal is too not have the gradient but the "tubularBarPlotWithColor" has gradient. I need help on displaying it without the shadows or gradient from using "tubularBarPlotWithColor"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+tubularBarPlotWithColor:` is a short cut to create bars with a gradient fill. If you don't want the gradient, set the `fill` to a solid color.

```
self.helloPlot.fill = [[CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]];
```